# Problem importing .stl files, it has a lot of faces and vertices

Tags: edit-mode, import, vertices, faces

I'm new to blender, but I just want to ask how to dissolve the faces in a quicker way, because importing stl and viewing it to edit mode shows a lot of unnecessary faces. I select faces and dissolve it, but I don't want that, I want a quicker way. If you don't get what I'm saying, here's an example:[image]

With dissolved faces:

[image]

I hope you understand what I'm saying. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove doubles first, <kbd>W</kbd> > <kbd>R</kbd>
2. If helpful, use the planar decimation modifier. It will create ngons though.
   [image]
3. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> is the shortcut for the tris to quad operation.
   [image]